# Installing other applications alongside WordPress multisite and configuring dns routing

Tags: multisite, subdomains, apache, dns

I have configured a subdomain on my server and in DNS at my registrar as I have done many times. I don't want this particular subdomain to use my multisite WordPress install but all requests are being routed to `http://mysite.co.uk/wp-signup.php?new=nameofsubdomain`.

Can anyone suggest what configuration step I have missed to prevent WordPress from receiving requests to subdomain.mysite.co.uk ?

How can I install other applications alongside a WordPress multisite install correctly?

This particular server is Ubuntu 14.04 running Apache2.x

I feel that this **DOES** relate to WordPress as the server configuration was previously set up only for WP multisite and I feel other WP admins would benefit from this knowledge.

Comment: running `a2ensite` resolved the problem so presumably I had done something wrong with my apache config. Please close if you feel that is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

codecowboy has reports in the comments for this question that the issue has been resolved:

> Running `a2ensite` resolved the problemm so presumably I had done
>   something wrong with my Apache config.